# *ngIf else go to the else template after a while

Tags: html, angular

Hi I have code that looks something like this :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="firstCondition; else ByeBye">
    <ng-container *ngIf="innerContainer">
       <div class="Hello Message">
         {{HelloMessage}}
       </div>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #ByeBye>
  Bye Bye my freind
</ng-template>
```

I get the HelloMessage, which means the firstCondition is true , but for some reason after few seconds (without doing anything) I see the "Bye Bye my freind" message.

Any Idea why I go to the else template?

Thank you!

Comment: can you put the code of the component class

Comment: Apparently something is changing `firstCondition` value to falsy.

Comment: @shaniklein I think your `firstCondition` is false after same time track `firstCondition` value how many time to get i html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, there is something is happening behind which changes the value of firstCondition. That's why it's happending. Better to debug the code. Use `debbugger` or `console` to check for which it is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Check where in your code the value of "firstCondition" is changed (maybe by a service or later loading data).

Also take into account that in Javascript, all of the following means that "firstCondition" is false:

```
- Boolean: false        
- Value: 0    
- String (empty): ''
- Undefined
- null
```